# Can I use @media not all in scss?

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

I'm using scss and I just want to disable hover features on mobile for a very specific section of code. It's a nested div using the & prefix. So, basically:

```
.superclass{

    .subclass{

        @media not all and (pointer: coarse) {
         &hover{
         hover style
         }
    }
}}
```

Would this work? Right now I'm dealing with build issues keeping me from deploying my application locally and verifying that way.

Comment: you shoud add &:hover.. you missied :

Comment: pls share workable code

Comment: No this won't work. You need to format the media query as @media screen and (max-width: 767px) - though this 767 is very arbitrary, basically less than the min width of a regular iPad - then reset the hover. Eg. if you have text-decoration: underline set it to none instead. Also know there's no hover on a mobile so the hover pseudo doesn't work on mobile anyway.

Comment: For the testing part, you can use scss in CodePen (and many other fiddling services)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a traditional size approach for mobile?

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```